# How do I move images side by side?

Tags: html, image, css

I am trying to create an index.html that features car parts and accessories. Similar to most car parts websites like AutoZone. I want the products to show with an img and description underneath.

I am aware that in CSS that I can float the images left but when I do so they come down in a diagonal instead horizontally across my screen.

enter code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Real Truck-Performance Parts & Accessories</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <nav id="nav"></nav>

  <body>
<img class="top-corner" src="front-end-dev-test/assets/realtruck_horizontal.svg" alt="">


    <div id="app">
      <img class="headerPic" src="front-end-dev-test/assets/truck.png" alt="Header Pic">

    </div>
<ul>


<div id="ProductList1">
      <img class="imageSize" src="front-end-dev-test/assets/wheel.png" alt="product"
      class="productClass" >
<div class="price"><span>Fuel Black Triton Wheels
<strong>From $90 </strong></span></div>


      <img class="imageSize" src="front-end-dev-test/assets/wheel.png" alt="product"
      class="productClass" >
<div class="price"><span>Fuel Black Triton Wheels</span></div>

<img class="imageSize" src="front-end-dev-test/assets/wheel.png" alt="product"
class="productClass" >
<div class="price"><span>Fuel Black Triton Wheels</span></div>
  </div>

  <div id="ProductList2">
    <img class="imageSize" src="front-end-dev-test/assets/wheel.png" alt="product"
    class="productClass" >
    <div class="price"><span>Fuel Black Triton Wheels</span></div>

    <img class="imageSize" src="front-end-dev-test/assets/wheel.png" alt="product"
    class="productClass" >
    <div class="price"><span>Fuel Black Triton Wheels</span></div>

    <img class="imageSize" src="front-end-dev-test/assets/wheel.png" alt="product"
    class="productClass" >
    <div class="price"><span>Fuel Black Triton Wheels</span></div>

  </div>

<div id="ProductList3">
    <img class="imageSize" src="front-end-dev-test/assets/wheel.png" alt="product"
    class="productClass" >
    <div class="price"><span>Fuel Black Triton Wheels</span></div>

    <img class="imageSize" src="front-end-dev-test/assets/wheel.png" alt="product"
    class="productClass" >
    <div class="price"><span>Fuel Black Triton Wheels</span></div>

    <img class="imageSize" src="front-end-dev-test/assets/wheel.png" alt="product"
    class="productClass" >
    <div class="price"><span>Fuel Black Triton Wheels</span></div>


  </div>

<div id="productList4">
    <img class="imageSize" src="front-end-dev-test/assets/wheel.png" alt="product"
  class="productClass" >
  <div class="price"><span>Fuel Black Triton Wheels</span></div>

  <img class="imageSize" src="front-end-dev-test/assets/wheel.png" alt="product"
      class="productClass" >
  <div class="price"><span>Fuel Black Triton Wheels</span></div>

  <img class="imageSize" src="front-end-dev-test/assets/wheel.png" alt="product"
      class="productClass" >
  <div class="price"><span>Fuel Black Triton Wheels</span></div>

  </div>


  </body>
  </ul>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include your css and HTML code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for solving well-written questions about programming related problems, possibly illustrated with feedback, bug reports, code snippets and links to illustrative images.

Comment: I added the HTML I am trying to style any help as far as CSS would be appreciated.

Comment: In my research I am seeing that I may be going for an e-commerce look.

Comment: @MikeWood I added the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got bored so I made this for you.

```js
var navbar = document.getElementById("nav-bar");
var menubtn = document.getElementById("menu-button");
var sidenav = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
var main = document.getElementById("main");
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

function toggleNav() {
  if (menubtn.classList.contains("change")) {
    sidenav.style.left = "-250px";
    main.style.marginLeft = "0";
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    navbar.style.position = "";
    navbar.style.marginLeft = "";
    menubtn.classList.remove("change");
  } else {
    sidenav.style.left = "0";
    main.style.marginLeft = "250px";
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    navbar.style.position = "absolute";
    navbar.style.marginLeft = "250px";
    menubtn.classList.add("change");
  }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == overlay) {
    sidenav.style.left = "-250px";
    main.style.marginLeft = "0";
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    navbar.style.position = "";
    navbar.style.marginLeft = "";
    menubtn.classList.remove("change");
  }
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Drop the ".t-" so that you target the body if you use this */
.t-body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu-container {
  position: absoulute;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 250px;
  left: -250px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.maxScreenSize {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
}

.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel a {
  color: black;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel a:hover {
  background-color: #b2b2b2;
}

.responsive-img {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.responsive-img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.columns {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 8px;
}

.price {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.price li {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price .grey {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.price .title {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #449d48;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .columns {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div class="t-body">
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <button class="accordion">Tires & Wheels</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <a href="#">Link One</a>
      <a href="#">Link Two</a>
      <a href="#">Link Three</a>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Body Parts</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <a href="#">Link One</a>
      <a href="#">Link Two</a>
      <a href="#">Link Three</a>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Interior Accessories</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <a href="#">Link One</a>
      <a href="#">Link Two</a>
      <a href="#">Link Three</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-bar" id="nav-bar">
    <div class="menu-container" id="menu-button" onclick="toggleNav();">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="maxScreenSize">
    <div id="main">
      <div id="overlay"></div>

      <!-- Row 1 -->
      <div class="columns">
        <ul class="price">
          <li class="responsive-img"><img src="https://www.carid.com/images/fuel/wheels/fuel-triton-deep-lip-black-milled-accents.jpg" alt="product"></li>
          <li class="title">Fuel Black Triton Wheels</li>
          <li class="grey">From $90</li>
          <li class="button" onclick="window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874090/how-do-i-move-images-side-by-side');">Check Inventory</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="columns">
        <ul class="price">
          <li class="responsive-img"><img src="https://www.carid.com/images/fuel/wheels/fuel-triton-deep-lip-black-milled-accents.jpg" alt="product"></li>
          <li class="title">Fuel Black Triton Wheels</li>
          <li class="grey">From $90</li>
          <li class="button" onclick="window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874090/how-do-i-move-images-side-by-side');">Check Inventory</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="columns">
        <ul class="price">
          <li class="responsive-img"><img src="https://www.carid.com/images/fuel/wheels/fuel-triton-deep-lip-black-milled-accents.jpg" alt="product"></li>
          <li class="title">Fuel Black Triton Wheels</li>
          <li class="grey">From $90</li>
          <li class="button" onclick="window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874090/how-do-i-move-images-side-by-side');">Check Inventory</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Row 2 -->
      <div class="columns">
        <ul class="price">
          <li class="responsive-img"><img src="https://www.carid.com/images/fuel/wheels/fuel-triton-deep-lip-black-milled-accents.jpg" alt="product"></li>
          <li class="title">Fuel Black Triton Wheels</li>
          <li class="grey">From $90</li>
          <li class="button" onclick="window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874090/how-do-i-move-images-side-by-side');">Check Inventory</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="columns">
        <ul class="price">
          <li class="responsive-img"><img src="https://www.carid.com/images/fuel/wheels/fuel-triton-deep-lip-black-milled-accents.jpg" alt="product"></li>
          <li class="title">Fuel Black Triton Wheels</li>
          <li class="grey">From $90</li>
          <li class="button" onclick="window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874090/how-do-i-move-images-side-by-side');">Check Inventory</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="columns">
        <ul class="price">
          <li class="responsive-img"><img src="https://www.carid.com/images/fuel/wheels/fuel-triton-deep-lip-black-milled-accents.jpg" alt="product"></li>
          <li class="title">Fuel Black Triton Wheels</li>
          <li class="grey">From $90</li>
          <li class="button" onclick="window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874090/how-do-i-move-images-side-by-side');">Check Inventory</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much a lot of your html matches mine now this is a great guide for me

Comment: No problem, It was fun!

Comment: Good job ! :)))

Comment: I wish I could hang with you, I'd be a sponge. A grateful sponge lol.

Comment: @DemetriBethel They should add a follow/friend button on here so you can stay connected with people. I'm not the greatest on here, I've seen some people that will blow your mind with the amount of knowledge they have in coding. Believe it or not i'm still a beginner. If I ever see an issue you have posted ill try my best to solve it and maybe throw in a little extra.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your CSS and see if it gets you want you want.

```
div {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: That didn't it separated my text and my images are in a line formation.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```css
.imageSize, .price{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:49%;
}
```

Display : inline-block; align block on the same row. Vertical align make them align on the middle. And if you specify width:49%, they will take the same width.

Did that answer your question ?

Comment: This placed my text side by side to my images this is better. I appreciate all of the help.